# mBluetoothGatt.getService(uuid) returns null

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my app , i am passng the UUID number of the hearing aid service as in the BLE sample from google i.e. 0000a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

But the getservice returns null means that the service is not supported by the BluetoothGatt .
Why is this happening , can anybody please help me .

Comment: Have you discovered the services?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to first discover all services for the given device per documentation.

> This function requires that service discovery has been completed for the given device.
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#getService(java.util.UUID)

```
@Override
    // New services discovered
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            BluetoothGattService mBluetoothGattService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString(serviceUUID));
            if (mBluetoothGattService != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Service characteristic UUID found: " + mBluetoothGattService.getUuid().toString());
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Service characteristic not found for UUID: " + serviceUUID);
        }
    }
```

Or you can just run a search

```
for (BluetoothGattService gattService : gattServices) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service UUID Found: " + gattService.getUuid().toString());
}
```

Comment: What if mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString(serviceUUID)) is null? what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try doing a full discover[1] of the remote database and then iterate through the services. Maybe you've got the UUID wrong.

[1] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#discoverServices()

Answer (score 0):

Your UUID is also wrong. It should be 0000a00X-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, not 0000a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb