# why i get a NullPointerException when i want to make a ble Adapter?

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to make a Ble Client, who sends Characteristics to a Server. But I get a NullPointerException. Can anyone help or know a good example?

This is the ErrorCode:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.lang.Object
>   android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null
>   object reference
>   at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:659)
>                                                                                  at com.nilhcem.blefun.mobile.interact.GattClient.initialize(GattClient.java:164)
>                                                                                  at com.nilhcem.blefun.mobile.interact.InteractActivity.onCreate(InteractActivity.java:23)

```
public boolean initialize() {
    // For API level 18 and above, get a reference to BluetoothAdapter through
    // Initializes Bluetooth adapter.
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager;
    bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    return true;
}

public void onClickgoforward(View v) {
            if (mGattClient != null) {
                mGattClient.moveForward();
            }
        }


public void moveForward() {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w("BLE", "BluetoothAdapter ist nicht installiert");
        return;
    }
    BluetoothGattService mService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(SERVICE_UUID);
    if (mService == null) {
        Log.w("BLE", "Service wurde nicht gefunden.");
        return;
    }

    BluetoothGattCharacteristic forwardcharacteristic = mService.getCharacteristic(CHARACTERISTIC_FORWARD_UUID);
    if (!mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(forwardcharacteristic)) {
        Log.w("BLE", "Failed to read");
    }
}
```

```
@Override

    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.interact_activity);

mGattClient.initialize();

        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.interact_button);

        

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {

                mGattClient.moveforward();

            }

        });
```

This is my oncreate Method in the GattClient Activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // Initializes Bluetooth adapter.
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
            (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();




}
```

Comment: Where do you call `initialize()` method?

Comment: @Yupi in the oncreate at the main Activity

Comment: Can you update code with `onCreate`?

Comment: @Yupi yes, of course

Comment: `mGattClient.initialize();` seems your `initialize()` method is not in same activity? I think problem is that you are calling `GattClient` before `BluetoothManager` is initialized.

Comment: @Yupi I make a oncreate in my other activity and wirite the code of initialize() in it. Now i get this Error: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.getService(java.util.UUID)' on a null object reference

Comment: That confirms my theory that exception is caused by `GattClient` somewhere in code (see on which line of code exception is pointing) you are trying tu use `GattClient` which is in that time `null`

Comment: @Yupi it's in the onClickgoforward method and at this BluetoothGattService mBackwardService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(SERVICE_UUID); But how i can fix that?

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556096/mbluetoothgatt-getserviceuuid-returns-null